# ERROR #1046: Data too long for column but both source and destination columns are of type char(1)

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have three databases that are all meant to be the same but unfortunately are all different versions of Mysql (not my decision and unable to change that currently) only MariaDb 10.4 do I get an error when trying to send all data from a view into a historical table.

```
INSERT INTO 
`destination`.historical_table
SELECT * FROM 
`source`.daily_table
```

There are no triggers and the flagged column has the same datatype CHAR(1) on both tables.
The source table is actually a view, could that be the problem? It works on my other two DBs...

Comment: What error message do you get? Are the table definitions identical (also using same character set)?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both the source and destination tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: So this was actually my own fault but an interesting issue that mariahdb 10.4.10 caught but mysql 5.6.33 and mariahdb 10.1.38 did not.

The table definitions were not identical, two columns were switched between source and destination causing the failure. On the other databases however they merely truncated the values to the correct size (thus inserting incorrect data as well).

More my fault than anything else but interesting and something to take note of nonetheless.